# Decode 2nd level response body to struct

Tags: go

I have 2 structs:

```
type List struct {
    ListID string `json:"listid"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Users []User `json:"users"`
}

type User struct {
    Email string `json:"email"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

I am calling an endpoint and successfully getting a response which has the structure below:

```
{
 "Results":[
  {"Email": "user1@domain.com", "Name": "test1" "State": "Active",…},
  {"Email": "user2@domain.com", "Name": "test2" "State": "Active",…},
  {"Email": "user3@domain.com", "Name": "test3", "State": "Active",…}
 ],
 "SomeOtherStuff": "email"
}
```

I am trying to decode the JSON response to my struct like this:

```
err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&list.Users)
```

But there is no "Results" attribute in my struct to map to. How can I map only the Results key of the response to my array of User structs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your data there are at least two options:

Decode into map[string]interface{}

```
m := create(map[string]interface{})
err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&m)
```

Then use the m["results"] key to get at your users.

Or you could Decode into a container struct then assign list.Users = container.Results.

```
type Container struct {
    Results []User `json:"Results"`
    SomeOtherStuff string `json:"SomeOtherStuff"`
}
```

To get an idea of structs for arbitrary json look at [json2go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/).

Comment: I used to second approach. Thank you